# Write test to check for runtimeerrors

Tags: go, testing

I am writing tests for an interpreter that panics for a number of syntactically valid input. This is a minimal example of how I do it:

```
package minimalexample

import (
    "testing"
)

func access(i int) string {
    return []string{"a", "b"}[i]
}

func TestAccess(t *testing.T) {
    tests := []struct {
        testdatum int
        expected  string
    }{
        {0, "a"},
        {2, ""},
        {1, "c"},
        {4, ""},
    }

    for _, tt := range tests {
        testAccess(tt, t)
    }
}

func testAccess(tt struct {
    testdatum int
    expected  string
}, t *testing.T) {

    defer func() {
        if err := recover(); err != nil {
        t.Errorf("Runtime error for testdatum %v: %q", tt.testdatum, err)

        }
    }()
    result := access(tt.testdatum)
    if result != tt.expected {
        t.Errorf("%v evaluates to %q, though it should be %q", tt.testdatum, result, tt.expected)
    }

}
```

The idea to handle panic is taken from https://golang.org/doc/effective_go#recover, however I do not know whether it is good practice to use it in **tests** like I do in the above example or there is some reason why it is to be preferred to just let the test fail until the runtime error is fixed.

The advantage of this setting is that I see what happens for all testcases, even if one of then causes panic. The reason that I am still hesitant to say that is a good solution is that I am unsure whether it is the tester's job to care about runtime errors or whether that should be dealt with by the developer that has to fix the code to make the tests pass.
Another reason is that after running a bunch of these tests, I get a msg from vscode that I don't understand but suspect to have something to do with the exhaustive deferring: "Running the contributed command: '_vscode_delegate_cmd_kms3v2s2' failed."

Comment: Do you have a particular reason why this test is especially likely to cause a panic?  What you've done here is made it so that when this test panics, it will still fail (like it would if you didn't recover), but the err value of the panic is not displayed, and subsequent tests will continue to run.

Comment: Actually, in this particular software, there are quite a few kinds of input that cause error - and there are several places in the code that are responsible for that, not only one - so I am using the technique above in more more than one test functions. In each of these tests, I wanted the test to recover to show at once which inputs cause an error - but your remark is already helpful! Of course, I should display the error! Thx!

Comment: I edited accordingly. Still - is that good practice?

Comment: @tiffi if it works for you and solves your problems - it's a good practice; if it does not - it's not.

Comment: @HymnsForDisco: in my actual tests, we got (and it is not only three places in the code that cause this): runtime error: integer divide by zero, runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference, runtime error: index out of range [0] with length 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's anything wrong with recovering panic in a test to catch it more cleanly,  except that it is possibly indicative of a poor design pattern where you (or the package author) are using `panic` for normal error handling.

See https://go-proverbs.github.io/

> Don't panic.

This isn't an actual rule, but let's invent a new proverb to illustrate a point:

> 10 errors for every panic, 10 panics for every recover.

(looking at the GitHub search results we'll see that this is vaguely accurate)

- https://github.com/search?l=Go&q=err&type=Code 12 million
- https://github.com/search?l=Go&q=panic&type=Code 3 million
- https://github.com/search?l=Go&q=recover&type=Code 0.5 million

The point being panics should be used sparingly, as often an error is more appropriate.  And recover should be used ever more sparingly, because panic means something went so wrong that it's unlikely there's any way to fix it.

As a result, you should never use a panic with the intent that it should be recovered under typical use.

**Again this is not a rule, it is just my philosophy about error handling in Go**

---

`panic`s should generally be reserved for particular circumstances.  There could be more, but here are the main 2 in my view.

1. There is something statically wrong with the program, i.e. the programmer is using the function outside of it's normal, safe usage. For example:

- Tried to access outside of the array bounds
- Tried to use a `nil` pointer

2. There is something *really* unexpectedly wrong with the environment conditions and the program can't continue.

The main, legitimate use of `recover` is for process isolation.  For example, with the standard library HTTP server, if the goroutine handling an HTTP request panics, the server will recover the panic in order to let that request crash alone, and allow the server process to keep running.

Comment: I wouldn't say that the author "uses" panic - he is just not careful with considering edge cases - hence I have written my tests. Good to know that there's a proverb "don't panic"

Comment: What you write about process isolation is interesting to me - can't we apply that to testing? Isn't that exactly what I am doing? isolating the interpreter process from my tests?

Comment: If you're testing an interpreter process which panics upon errors within the interpreted context, then process isolation seems like an appropriate solution. To go back to your question, this is only bad practice, in my opinion, if you extend this practice to other forms of testing that don't warrant this process isolation pattern (which is probably most forms of testing).  The other legitimate use case I know of for recover in testing is for test cases that are *supposed to panic*, i.e, the doc says that the function *will* panic if ... See https://golang.org/src/time/tick_test.go#L112

Comment: Thank you! The last example is particularly interesting!